# Error while preprocessing the data in python - machine learning project for predicting stock prices using lstm

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

While running the command `df = df['open'].values`, I am getting this error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), NumPy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices. Could you tell me what could be causing the issue?

The completed code till the error is given below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from keras.models import Sequential, load_model
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense, Dropout
import os 
import tensorflow as tf

df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\xxx\Downloads\AAPL.csv')
df.head()
df = df['open'].values
df = df.reshape(-1,1)
print(df.shape)
df[:7]
```

Excecuting this returns the error ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)

```
<ipython-input-11-ccc5d87305f2> in <module>
----> 1 df = df['open'].values
      2 df = df.reshape(-1,1)
      3 print(df.shape)
      4 df[:7]
```

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

If it means I cant process floating values, what can be done to solve this issue? Most stock opening prices are in float. I am a beginner in machine learning and I am doing this as my final year engineering project.

Comment: This is a notebook related issue. Once you run that cell starting with `df = df['open'].values...`, `df` becomes a NumPy array. Then, if you run this cell again, you get that error. So: quick fix is to read the CSV again (or restart the kernel). Then you can rename `open_values = df["open"].values` so that *the* dataframe `df` doesn't change.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Thanks man for the quick help. I was confused for a long time about how it did run the first time and started screwing around the second time. I thought I made some syntax error somewhere and have been searching the entire code for where I made the error even though it's only 8-10 lines.  Thanks Thanks Thanks.